# Select rows containing a NaN following a specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new DataFrame consisting of the rows corresponding to the value 1.0 or NaN in the last column, whereby I only take the Nans under a 1.0 (that is, I'm interested in everything until a 0.0 appears).

```
Timestamp      Value         Mode    
00-00-10   34567  1.0  
00-00-20   45425     
00-00-30   46773  0.0  
00-00.40   64567   
00-00-50   25665  1.0  
00-00-60   25678
```

My attempt is:

```
for row in data.itertuples():
while data[data.Mode != 0.0]:
    df2 = df2.append(row)
else:
    #How do I differentiate between a NaN under a 1.0 and a NaN under a 0.0?
print (df2)
```

The idea is to save every row until a 0.0 appears, and afterwards ignore every row until a 1.0 appears again.

Comment: Your example doesn't include a `NaN`

Comment: I'm not sure the title matches the question at all

Comment: if you `read_clipboard` then `pandas` is smart enough to fill it with `NaN`, but yeah perhaps the example should be edited to have `NaN` in the input to be clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.ffill` to figure out if it's a `NaN` below a 1 or a 0.

Here are the `NaN` values below a 1

```
df[(df['Mode'].isnull()) & df['Mode'].ffill() == 1]
#  Timestamp  Value  Mode
#1  00-00-20  45425   NaN
#5  00-00-60  25678   NaN
```

To get all of the `1`s and `NaN` below:

```
df[((df['Mode'].isnull()) & df['Mode'].ffill() == 1) | df.Mode == 1]
#  Timestamp  Value  Mode
#0  00-00-10  34567   1.0
#1  00-00-20  45425   NaN
#4  00-00-50  25665   1.0
#5  00-00-60  25678   NaN
```

---

You can get away with slightly nicer logic, since you have only 1 and 0, though this might not always work due to the `NaN` in `'Mode'` (It seems to work for the above bit)

```
df[((df['Mode'].isnull()) & df['Mode'].ffill()) | df.Mode]
```